# Combobox.DataSource using int array not working

Tags: c#, nullpointerexception, datasource

I have 3 Comboboxes. One for COM port, one for baud rate, and one for a delay. At one point they all worked, but for some strange reason it is no longer working. There are no exceptions until I go to load my form then I get a NullPointerException. That happens because my Load event does not get fired and with some searching someone suggested that their DataSource was to blame. Sure enough I commented out my DataSource and I no longer got a null pointer exception.

but what baffles me is why.

```
        this.comportCombo.DataSource = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        this.comportCombo.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.comportCombo.SelectedValueChanged += comportCombo_SelectedValueChanged;

        this.baudRatCombo.DataSource = new int[] { 4800, 9600, 19200, 115200 };
        this.baudRatCombo.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.baudRatCombo.SelectedValueChanged += baudRatCombo_SelectedValueChanged;

        this.delayCombo.DataSource = new int[] { 50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500 }; //Code I comment out to stop the NPE.
        this.delayCombo.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.delayCombo.SelectedValueChanged += delayCombo_SelectedValueChanged;
```

BaudRatCombo works just fine. So I tried a dumb solution of putting only 4 numbers and still nothing. I'm completly baffled by this. My debugger isn't helping me too much on this either. Any suggestions? I've tried commenting out dalyCombo.DataSource (gets rid of my NPE) I've tried commenting out the other 2 comboboxes. I'm at a loss. Please help.

**UPDATE**

```
public class IInputDialog : Form
{
    public IInputDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += SerialPortDialog_Load;
    }
    public IInputDialog(IInput iinput)
        : this()
    {
        this._iinput = iinput;
    }

    void SerialPortDialog_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Doesn't Fire with DelayCombo.DataSource
        if (this._iinput != null)
        {
            serialPortTablePanel.IInput = this._iinput;
        }
    }

    public static IInput GetIInputDialog(IInput iinput)
    {
        IInput temp = iinput;
        using (IInputDialog icb = new IInputDialog(iinput))
        {
            if (icb.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                temp = icb.serialPortTablePanel.IInput;
        }
        return temp;
    }
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        this.serialPortTablePanel = new IInputTablePanel();
        this.serialPortTablePanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(serialPortTablePanel);
        this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(501, 562);

        this.ResumeLayout(false);
    }
    private IInputTablePanel serialPortTablePanel;
    private IInput _iinput;
}
```

**SerialPortWedgeTablePanel (partial)**

```
internal class IInputTablePanel : Control
{
    internal IInputTablePanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {

        SetupTestGroupBox(ref gb1, ref split1);


        tbl.Controls.Add(gb1, 0, 2);


    }

    private void SetupTestGroupBox(ref GroupBox gb1, ref SplitContainer split1)
    {
        this.comportCombo.DataSource = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        this.comportCombo.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        this.comportCombo.SelectedValueChanged += comportCombo_SelectedValueChanged;

        this.baudRatCombo.DataSource = new int[] { 4800, 9600, 19200, 115200 };
        this.baudRatCombo.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        this.baudRatCombo.SelectedValueChanged += baudRatCombo_SelectedValueChanged;

        this.delayCombo.DataSource = new int[] { 50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500 };
        this.delayCombo.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        this.delayCombo.SelectedValueChanged += delayCombo_SelectedValueChanged;

        gb1.Controls.Add(split1);
        gb1.Controls.Add(delayCombo);
        gb1.Controls.Add(baudRatCombo);
        gb1.Controls.Add(comportCombo);
        //gb1.Controls.Add(GetDefaultGroupBox("Input Delay", delayCombo));
        //gb1.Controls.Add(GetDefaultGroupBox("Baud Rate", baudRatCombo));
        //gb1.Controls.Add(GetDefaultGroupBox("Port Name", comportCombo));

        gb1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        gb1.Enabled = false;
        gb1.Font = new Font("Arial", 10F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, 0x00);
        gb1.Margin = new Padding(0);
        gb1.Padding = new Padding(10, 3, 10, 10);
        gb1.Text = "Serial Port Options";
    }

    void delayCombo_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _iinput.Delay = (int)this.delayCombo.SelectedItem;
    }
    void baudRatCombo_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _serialPort.BaudRate = (int)baudRatCombo.SelectedItem;
    }
    void comportCombo_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _serialPort.PortName = comportCombo.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }

    internal IInput IInput
    {
        get {return _iinput;}
        set
        {
            this._iinput = value;
            this.delayCombo.SelectedItem = value.Delay;
            if (value is ComPortInput)
            {
                this.comportCombo.SelectedItem = (value as ComPortInput).serialPort.PortName; //string[]
                this.baudRatCombo.SelectedItem = (value as ComPortInput).serialPort.BaudRate; //object[]
                _serialPort = (value as ComPortInput).serialPort;
            }
        }
    }

    private void SuspendLayouts(params Control[] args)
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        foreach(Control c in args)
            c.SuspendLayout();
    }
    private void ResumeLayouts(bool resume, params Control[] args)
    {
        foreach (Control c in args)
            c.ResumeLayout(resume);

        this.ResumeLayout(resume);
    }


    private Button testButt;
    private ClickComboBox comportCombo = new ClickComboBox();
    private ClickComboBox baudRatCombo = new ClickComboBox();
    private ClickComboBox delayCombo = new ClickComboBox();
    private System.IO.Ports.SerialPort _serialPort = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort();
    private IInput _iinput;
}
internal class ClickComboBox : System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
{
    internal ClickComboBox()
    {
        this.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 24F);
        this.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.ItemHeight = 37;
        this.Click += ClickComboBox_Click;
    }

    void ClickComboBox_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new System.Action(() => this.DroppedDown = true));
    }
}
```

**Update2**

I just tried this and it works as expected...

```
        this.delayCombo.Items.AddRange(new object[] { 50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500 });
        this.delayCombo.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        this.delayCombo.SelectedValueChanged += delayCombo_SelectedValueChanged;
```

funny enough so does baud rate.. So they both take the same arguments (a int array) and they are almost identicle in every respect with exceptions to location and the array. I don't get it. I don't want to use different ways of adding data, but it is working.. :/

Comment: can you show the code that you commented out along with your Load event?

Comment: Any way you can post the code from SerialPortDialog and the code that instantiates it?